# How to replace Google website Dropdown with specified languages

Tags: javascript, google-translate

> I have integrated google website translator with my web site but i
>   need only English and French languages in dropdown. How can i change the drop down
>   list?

Comment: thanq for added another tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have to add includedLanguages: 'en,fr' as mentioned below...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en',includedLanguages: 'en,fr', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'ar', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: this ar will work as a default language but this is not my question.